# trouble with the "else" commands

Tags: c#, .net

this is my current code, my else command doesn' work. how can i make it so if any someone typed in something that is not recognized the console writes im sorry that is an unrecognzied commands type help for a list of commands but it doesn't write this if the command is recognized

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1

{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {



        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
        string UserName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("hello {0} what would you like me to do", UserName);
        do
        {
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            if (line == "time") Console.WriteLine("its {1}", UserName, System.DateTime.UtcNow);
            if (line == "help") Console.WriteLine("TIME: shows current time and date");
            if (line == "easter egg") Console.WriteLine("this code does funk all");
            if (line == "easter egg") Console.WriteLine("well done on finding an easter egg {0}", UserName);
            if (line == "juggle") Console.WriteLine("im sorry {0} but im not very good at party tricks", UserName);
            if (line == else) Console.WriteLine("im sorry that is an unrecognzied commands type help for a list of commands");

            Console.WriteLine("anything else");

        }
        while (string.Equals(Console.ReadLine(), "yes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Look into switch/case at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx
your else is like "default"

Comment: What `if (line == else)` supposed to do? This even will not compile.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong with the If statement, you need curly braces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably your code should look like this:

```
if (line == "time") 
    Console.WriteLine("its {1}", UserName, System.DateTime.UtcNow);
else if (line == "help") 
    Console.WriteLine("TIME: shows current time and date");
else if (line == "easter egg") 
    Console.WriteLine("this code does funk all");
else if (line == "easter egg") 
    Console.WriteLine("well done on finding an easter egg {0}", UserName);
else if (line == "juggle") 
    Console.WriteLine("im sorry {0} but im not very good at party tricks", UserName);
else
    Console.WriteLine("im sorry that is an unrecognzied commands type help for a list of commands");
```

But double checking of `if (line == "easter egg")` with different result looks strange for me, and in this case second "easter egg" branch will never executed. Probably, there is some typo here?

Or, if it was intended, that part of code concerning "easter egg" branch should look like

```
else if (line == "easter egg") 
{
    Console.WriteLine("this code does funk all");
    Console.WriteLine("well done on finding an easter egg {0}", UserName);
}
```

Comment: The line `Console.WriteLine("well done on finding an easter egg {0}", UserName);` wont execute, to be identical to before, you would need to put both statements into the same `if` block

Comment: @Matthew yes, I've already saw it and updated answer. Probably it's just typo or copy-pasting issue of OP - I don''t know. Maybe it should be two lines be printed in this case - it's up to OP.

Answer (score 8):

More applicable in this particular scenario would be a [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement. It's great when you need to execute different code based on one input value.

```
switch(line)
{
    case "time":       Console.WriteLine("its {1}", UserName, System.DateTime.UtcNow); break; // By the way, why pass in UserName if you aren't going to use it?
    case "help":       Console.WriteLine("TIME: shows current time and date"); break;
    case "easter egg": Console.WriteLine("well done on finding an easter egg {0}", UserName); break;
    case "juggle":     Console.WriteLine("im sorry {0} but im not very good at party tricks", UserName); break;
    default:           Console.WriteLine("im sorry that is an unrecognzied commands type help for a list of commands");
}
```

In the example above, the value of `line` will be compared to the string after each `case` statement. If a match is found, the code for that statement will execute. If no match is found, the code for the default statement will execute.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are trying to write your code is not how if/else statements work. The correct syntax is:

```
if (a == 0)
{
  // do something when a is 0
}
else
{
  // do something when a isn't 0
}
```

If you have multiple cases to check you can add an `else if`.

```
if (a == 0)
{
  // do something when a is 0
}
else if (a < 0)
{
  // do something when a is less than 0
}
else
{
  // do something when a is greater than 0
}
```

In your case, you are checking if a single variable has one of a number of values. This pattern is common enough, that it has it's own syntax. It is called a switch statement.

```
switch(line)
{
    case "time":
       // do something when value is "time"
       break;
    case "help":
       // do something when value is "help"
       break;
   default:
       // do something when value is any value that you did not explicitly list
       break;
}
```

Note the `default` case in the switch statement. This is what you are trying to achieve with you incorrect `line == else` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the if/else statements properly, here's how to use them.

```
        if (line == "time") {Console.WriteLine("its {1}", UserName, System.DateTime.UtcNow);}
        else if (line == "help") {Console.WriteLine(string.Format("TIME: {0}", DateTime.Now);}
        else if (line == "easter egg") {Console.WriteLine("this code does fuck all");}
        else if (line == "easter egg") {Console.WriteLine("well done on finding an easter egg {0}", UserName);}
        else if (line == "juggle") {Console.WriteLine("im sorry {0} but im not very good at party tricks", UserName);}
        else { Console.WriteLine("im sorry that is an unrecognzied commands type help for a list of commands");}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it does not work, is because `else` is a reserved keyword. `else` is part of the `if` statement itself, you can't compare a value to else. See [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx) to get more info about if - else.

As other have resolved it already using the if-else statements, here is an example with switch-case. It's a little different construction but works practically the same.

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
switch(line)
{
    case "time":
        Console.WriteLine("its {1}", UserName, System.DateTime.UtcNow);
        break;
    case "help":
        Console.WriteLine("TIME: shows current time and date");
        break;
    case "easter egg":
        Console.WriteLine("this code does fuck all");
        Console.WriteLine("well done on finding an easter egg {0}", UserName);
        break;
    case "juggle":
        Console.WriteLine("im sorry {0} but im not very good at party tricks", UserName);
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("im sorry that is an unrecognzied commands type help for a list of commands");
        break;
}
```